# How to find the required term in such series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a series $1-2+3-4+5 \ldots$ till infinity. now I make some changes and convert the first two minus to plus to get $(10)+5-6+7-8 \ldots$ till infinity. Now I can make the $10$ to sum up to zero only by using $-1$ which I will get by using $(5-6)$, $(7-8)$, $(9-10)$ etc. After using required no. of such pairs, I will get a positive number. Now to make that number zero, I will again use the pairs. If we continue the pattern, what is the $100$th positive number obtained by us?

Comment: You cannot use ordinery addition/subtraction on a set contains infinitely many elements

Comment: Yes, but I am limiting the sum to finite terms. And not using ordinary calculations in the question is the challenge of the question